# Use Parse.com in a Qt Android App

Tags: android, qt, background-process, qt5.3

I would like to have a background service running all time that register the device using the Parse API and emits Push Notifications, while having the main app developed in Qt with QML/JS. My question is: Is this possible? How can I do it? Is there any code-like example or documentation?

This is because I would like to write my application using Qt (QML + JS) and use Parse on the server side with it's PHP SDK.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

this should help (commercial solution):

http://plugins.v-play.net/plugins/parse/